# Scraping Clinical Studies database (via ClinicalTrials.Gov)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, hash-map, beautifulsoup

I have written the following script to scrape data from [the U.S. National Library of Medicine website *ClinicalTrials.Gov*](https://ClinicalTrials.Gov) based on an NCTID.

```
def clinicalTrialsGov (nctid):
    data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" + nctid + "?displayxml=true").text, "xml")
    subset = ['study_type', 'allocation', 'intervention_model', 'primary_purpose', 'masking', 'enrollment', 'official_title', 'condition', 'minimum_age', 'maximum_age', 'gender', 'healthy_volunteers', 'phase', 'primary_outcome', 'secondary_outcome', 'number_of_arms']
    tag_matches = data.find_all(subset)
    tag_dict = dict((str('ct' + tag_matches[i].name.capitalize()), tag_matches[i].text) for i in range(0, len(tag_matches)))
    tag_dict = multipleFields(data, ['intervention_name'], tag_dict)
    tag_dict = multipleFields(data, ['intervention_type'], tag_dict)
    tag_dict = multipleFields(data, ['arm_group_type'], tag_dict)
    tag_dict['ctID'] = nctid
    #for key in tag_dict:
        #print(key + ': ' + tag_dict[key])
    return removeEmptyKeys(tag_dict)

def multipleFields (data, subset, tagDict):
    fields = data.find_all(subset)
    field = []
    try:
        for each in fields:
            field.append(each.text)
        tagDict[str('ct' + subset[0].capitalize())] = ", ".join(field)
        return tagDict
    except:
        return tagDict

def removeEmptyKeys (dict1):
    newDict = {}
    for key in dict1:
        if str(dict1[key]) is not '':
            newDict[key] = dict1[key]
    return newDict
```

What can I do to make this process more efficent?

Comment: How many NCTIDs are you planning on scraping? If you need more than one you should look into  [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and possibly [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/).

Comment: @Graipher I plan on scraping around 100,000 NCTIDs.

Comment: FYI the data on ClinicalTrials.gov is also available in a [publicly available PostgreSQL database](https://aact.ctti-clinicaltrials.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not too late.

There are a few things you could do :

**Solution 1**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

def clinicalTrialsGov (nctid):
    data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" + nctid + "?displayxml=true").text, "xml")
    subset = ['study_type', 'allocation', 'intervention_model', 'primary_purpose', 'masking', 'enrollment', 'official_title', 'condition', 'minimum_age', 'maximum_age', 'gender', 'healthy_volunteers', 'phase', 'primary_outcome', 'secondary_outcome', 'number_of_arms']
    tag_matches = data.find_all(subset)
    tag_dict = {'ct' + current_tag.name.capitalize(): current_tag.text for current_tag in tag_matches}
    tag_dict = multipleFields(data, 'intervention_name', tag_dict)
    tag_dict = multipleFields(data, 'intervention_type', tag_dict)
    tag_dict = multipleFields(data, 'arm_group_type', tag_dict)
    tag_dict['ctID'] = nctid
    return removeEmptyKeys(tag_dict)

def multipleFields (data, subset, tagDict):
    fields = data.find_all(subset)
    field = [each.text for each in fields]
    tagDict['ct' + subset.capitalize()] = ", ".join(field)
    return tagDict

def removeEmptyKeys (dict1):
    newDict = {k:v for (k, v) in dict1.items() if v}
    return newDict

pprint.pprint(clinicalTrialsGov("NCT01220960"))
```

- I have used a dictionary comprehension to define `tag_dict` and `newDict`. This is similar to a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) but specialized for dictionaries
- I have removed the `try … except` from `multipleFields` because I don't see in which case an exception will be raised (especially since you didn't specify which one you were trying to catch)
- I have presumed that `subset` in `multipleFields()` is a string and not a list of strings since you were looking only for one tag
- I have used a list comprehension to define `field` in `multipleFields()`
- I have used the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module to see better the answer.

Answer (score 0):

But we can go further:

**Solution 2**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

def clinicalTrialsGov (nctid):
    data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" + nctid + "?displayxml=true").text, "xml")
    subset = ['study_type', 'allocation', 'intervention_model',
              'primary_purpose', 'masking', 'enrollment',
              'official_title', 'condition', 'minimum_age',
              'maximum_age', 'gender', 'healthy_volunteers',
              'phase', 'primary_outcome', 'secondary_outcome',
              'number_of_arms', 'intervention_name',
              'intervention_type', 'arm_group_type']
    tag_dict = {f'ct{subset_detail.capitalize()}' : [current_tag.text
                                                     for current_tag
                                                     in data.find_all(subset_detail)
                                                     if current_tag.text.strip()]
                for subset_detail in subset}
    result_data = {k: ", ".join(v) for (k, v) in tag_dict.items() if v} 
    result_data['ctID'] = nctid
    return result_data

pprint.pprint(clinicalTrialsGov("NCT01220960"))
```

- Instead of looking for almost all tags at the same time, I use a dictionary comprehension to look for each tag seperately and creating a list containing the text retrieved linked to the tag. This works if there's zero, one or many matching tags.
- I created another dictionary (`result_data`) to merge the answers (if there's more than one) and filter out the tags that don't have text associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at the xml data coming in and I noticed that, for example, 'primary_outcome' and 'secondary_outcome' includes other tags ('measure', 'timeframe' and 'description'). Maybe you need all the information in tags but if you needed to retreive only the 'measure' for these tags you could do something like this:

**Solution 3**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

def clinicalTrialsGov (nctid):
    data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" + nctid + "?displayxml=true").text, "xml")
    subset = ['study_type', 'allocation', 'intervention_model',
              'primary_purpose', 'masking', 'enrollment',
              'official_title', 'condition', 'minimum_age',
              'maximum_age', 'gender', 'healthy_volunteers',
              'phase', 'number_of_arms', 'intervention_name',
              'intervention_type', 'arm_group_type']
    subset_has_measure = ['primary_outcome', 'secondary_outcome',]

    tag_dict = {f'ct{subset_detail.capitalize()}' : [current_tag.text for current_tag in data.find_all(subset_detail)]
                for subset_detail in subset}
    tag_dict_with_measure = {f'ct{subset_detail.capitalize()}' : [current_tag.text
                                                                  for current_tag
                                                                  in data.select(f'{subset_detail} measure')]
                             for subset_detail in subset_has_measure}
    result_data = {k: ", ".join(v) for (k, v) in tag_dict.items() if v}
    result_data.update((k, ", ".join(v)) for (k, v) in tag_dict_with_measure.items() if v)
    result_data['ctID'] = nctid
    return result_data

pprint.pprint(clinicalTrialsGov("NCT01220960"))
```

- Instead of using `.find_all()` I use `.select()` which enables us to use a CSS expression to the tag we want

You could in fact generalize this situation for something else than 'measure':

**Solution 4**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint

def clinicalTrialsGov (nctid):
    data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/" + nctid + "?displayxml=true").text, "xml")
    subset = { '': ['study_type', 'allocation', 'intervention_model',
                    'primary_purpose', 'masking', 'enrollment',
                    'official_title', 'condition', 'minimum_age',
                    'maximum_age', 'gender', 'healthy_volunteers', 'phase',
                    'number_of_arms', 'intervention_name', 'intervention_type',
                    'arm_group_type'],
               'measure': ['primary_outcome', 'secondary_outcome',]
               }
    tag_dict = {f'ct{subset_detail.capitalize()}' : [current_tag.text
                                                     for current_tag
                                                     in data.select(f'{subset_detail} {subset_category}')]
                for (subset_category, subset_types) in subset.items() for subset_detail in subset_types}
    result_data = {k: ", ".join(v) for (k, v) in tag_dict.items() if v}
    result_data['ctID'] = nctid
    return result_data

pprint.pprint(clinicalTrialsGov("NCT01220960"))
```